# Two sets of data in one component

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing data to a component with no issue - however, I'd now like to re-use that component with a different data set:

```
import React from 'react';

const people = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    age: 32,
    hobby: "jogging",
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: "John",
    age: 32,
    hobby: "jogging",
}];

const cars = [{
    id: 1,
    manufacturer: "Ford",
    model: "Focus",
    year: "2014",
  },{
    id: 2,
    manufacturer: "Honda",
    model: "Civic",
    year: "2012",
}];

export default function ListGroup(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.people.map((person) =>
        <li key={person.id}>
           <p>Name: {person.name}</p>
           <p>Hobby: {person.hobby}</p>
        </li>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above code works perfectly for the `people` fixture, but to use the same component I'm not sure what the simplest path might be. Any guidance welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the ids using  `Object.keys(component).map(function(attributes){}`. I have presented it like a component you can use it like a function as well. I hope you can convert it to how you want to use it.

```js
class ListGroup extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
 }
 render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.value.map((component) => {
       
       return (
        <li key={component.id}>
           {Object.keys(component).map(function(attributes) {
               
               return (
                <p>{attributes} : {component[attributes]}</p>
               )
           }, this)}
           
        </li>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
}


}

class Hello extends React.Component {
constructor() {
  super();
}

  
  render() {
    const people = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    age: 32,
    hobby: "jogging",
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: "John",
    age: 32,
    hobby: "jogging",
}];

const cars = [{
    id: 1,
    manufacturer: "Ford",
    model: "Focus",
    year: "2014",
  },{
    id: 2,
    manufacturer: "Honda",
    model: "Civic",
    year: "2012",
}];
      return (
        <div>
          <ListGroup value={people} />
          <ListGroup value={cars} />
        </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello /> ,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This answers my question, but this seems somewhat inflexible - for example, what if there are different numbers of props? or an object or array? or if styling should be applied differently in case of missing props? Thanks for the response, just trying to understand.